# AngularJS and 'Controller as' syntax with ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-ui-grid

I am having issues finding out why the filter is undefined...

Uncaught ReferenceError: filter is not defined(anonymous function) @ mainController.js:46(anonymous function) @ mainController.js:76

What am I missing?

Index =

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-open="main.refreshData()">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/site.css">
    <!--<link data-require="ui-grid@*" data-semver="3.0.0RC18" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/ui-grid.css">-->
    <link data-require="ui-grid@*" data-semver="3.0.0RC18" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Application/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="Application/mainController.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController as main">

    <input type="text" ng-model="main.food" placeholder="Enter food" />

    <p>Sriracha sauce is great with {{main.food}}!</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.filterText" ng-change="refreshData()" placeholder="Search..." />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h>{{main.title}}</h>
    <div class="grid" ui-grid='main.gridOptions' id="grid1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

app =

```
//The app.module.js file houses a single application-level module for your application. 
//In this example, your application has an application-level module that loads the 
//other modules of the application. The purpose of adding app.module.js as a separate 
//file is to introduce the concept that modules, controllers, services, directives, 
//views, etc. should be defined in their own files.


//<<Immediately-invoked function expression>>
//Immediately-invoked function expressions can be used to avoid variable hoisting from 
//within blocks, protect against polluting the global environment and simultaneously 
//allow public access to methods while retaining privacy for variables defined within the function.
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []);

})();
```

Controller =

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ui.grid'])
        .controller('MainController', main);


    function main() {

        var self = this;
        self.food = 'pizza';

        self.myData = [{
            name: "Moroni",
            age: 50
        }, {
            name: "Tiancum",
            age: 43
        }, {
            name: "Jacob",
            age: 27
        }, {
            name: "Nephi",
            age: 29
        }, {
            name: "Enos",
            age: 34
        }];

        self.gridOptions = {
            data: "main.myData",
            enableGridMenu: true
        };

        self.title = "ng-grid Example";

        self.filterText;

        self.refreshData = function () {
            self.gridOptions.data = self.filter('filter')(self.myData, self.filterText, undefined);
        };
    }

    //Define a custom filter to search only visible columns (used with grid 3)
    filter('visibleColumns', function () {
        return function (data, grid, query) {

            matches = [];

            //no filter defined so bail
            if (query === undefined || query === '') {
                return data;
            }

            query = query.toLowerCase();

            //loop through data items and visible fields searching for match
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < grid.columnDefs.length; j++) {

                    var dataItem = data[i];
                    var fieldName = grid.columnDefs[j]['field'];

                    //as soon as search term is found, add to match and move to next dataItem
                    if (dataItem[fieldName].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1) {
                        matches.push(dataItem);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return matches;
        }
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translate your filter to function and bind it to application.

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.grid'])
    .controller('MainController', main)
    .filter('visibleColumns', visibleColumns);

function visibleColumns () {...}
```

There is no function `filter()`, there is method of `angular.module` Object that called `filter('name', function() { ... })`.

[More about custom filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

Comment: OK, so I added   .filter('visibleColumns', visibleColumns);   to the angular.module

And that makes sense to register it there.  

But I am now getting the same error for visibleColumns not being defined

Comment: looking through the custom filters link you have, I am not sure on any conversion syntax for this ...

Comment: ok, i changed filter('visibleColumns'....

to 

function visibleColumns() {

A regular function 

There are no compile errors, but nothing happens when text is entered into the Search filter box...

Comment: UPDATE: I got the code working.  It took several clean up items where data need to be defined as the filter expected, and that the refreshData needed to be called with the myData,

Comment: I recommend you to move controller and filter to separate files as well.